# MongoDB hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm newbie in mongo database ,I want to know if  can create database and tables with hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto  values create,update,validate.I created Documents classes but Database didn't created.

Comment: Hibernate can't be used to store data in MongoDB. And MongoDB doesn't use tables. The question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I'd assume the OP uses [Hibernate OGM](http://hibernate.org/ogm/) which allows to access MongoDB via Hibernate/JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot use the regular hibernate with NoSQL DBs like MongoDB. You can try Hibernate OGM or Morphia. Personally, I have used Morphia and it does it's job.

Morphia - https://github.com/mongodb/morphia

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use [Hibernate OGM](http://hibernate.org/ogm/) to access MongoDB. In this case specify the following property to have the database automatically created:

```
hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database=true
```

You can find a list with all available options in the [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#_mongodb_specific_configuration_properties). You also might be interested in issue [OGM-571](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-571) which is about honoring the existing `hbm2ddl` setting.